# GeoServer ImageMosaic Dimensions are not enabled when Layer is created by OpenSearch EO Plugin

Tags: geoserver, opensearch

I have a problem with GeoServer and the OpenSearch plugin (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/opensearch-eo/index.html).

In particular, I want to both use the OpenSearch module for search purposes and to publish an Image Mosaics for each collection.

In order to do this, I follow this tutorial/documentation:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/opensearch-eo/automation.html#usage-of-the-api-for-search-and-integrated-ogc-service-publishing.

However, although the plugin creates the (Image Mosaic) layer correctly, I cannot enable the Dimension Attribute for that layer (as you can see in the [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKW3Y.png)).

I am using GeoServer version 2.20.2, specifically the kartoza/geoserver:2.20.2 docker image: 2.20.2, and the 1.0 version of the OpenSearch plugin.

Is there anyone who can help me solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Dimension Tab on GeoServer on Layer created by OpenSearch Plugin]

Comment: does your image mosaic have a time index?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! Yes! In the OpenSearch configuration I created a PostGIS database in which there are collections, products and granules. Time Attribute is in the product table, and in the configuration files that OpenSearch automatically creates, there is a mapping between the attribute name in product table and the ImageMosaic TimeAttribute.